# Система автоматизированного тестирования веб приложения

Tags: юнит-тесты, php, html

Есть ли артенативы Selenium-у? Нужно чтобы тест мог заполнять поля, переходить по ссылке и особенно важно чтобы мог проверить изначальные данные которые даются и конечные данные.

Comment: может и есть, главный вопрос - чем селениум не устраивает ?

Comment: Потому что нужно будет установить unittest, selenium и еще что-то. А хочется простой интерфейс.

Comment: простой интерфейс - меньше возможностей, гугл чем не угодил ? на SO вон сколько альтернатив.

Comment: Уточните, под какую ОС разыскиваете.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04